# How to convert a 220 VAC to DC switch mode power supply to use 110 V

Tags: power-supply, power, switch-mode-power-supply, mains

I'm new to the electronics stack exchange and I have a pretty basic question.
How can I convert my 220 VAC to 5 V switching power supply, to run off 110 VAC?

I purchased a few 5 V 40 A power supplies to power some LED panels for a project. Little did I know the input for the supplies are rated for 190 - 220 VAC. If I use 110 VAC I do not get a constant supply, but rather an intermittent 5V output.

My transformer and power supply knowledge is pretty basic. Is it possible for me to change the capacitor values to give a constant supply?

Thanks for your help in advance!

[image: The interior of the switch mode power supply]

Comment: My guess is no, but do you have a schematic for your power supply?

Comment: It's possible that your power supply was designed to be factory configurable for either a 220V or 110V supply. But without a lot more detail there's no way to tell from this side of the web.

Comment: From a quick glance I’d suggest you buy suitable power supplies as modifying your current ones would be challenging

Answer (score 2):

Realistically, it would be a challenge.

You would need to:-

- Reverse engineer the board to get a circuit diagram
- Identify the chip set used
- Find the manufacturer's data sheets
- See if they tell you what components to use for different supply voltages
- Modify the circuit board to match the new design

Answer (score 1):

It is this one here https://www.ledcontrollercard.com/english/south-creative-nda200hs5-led-screen-power-supply.html

Nominal input voltage is 220 V AC, minimal 190 V, maximal 264 V.

You need another supply for 110 V AC.